# How to save data unlimited data to mongodb collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to save the data from an API coinbase pro, The loop will run until all data is fetched and is being saved to mongodb collection. But the main issue is when we reach 16MB , the script fails.

I need a viable solution to save unlimited data to mongodb collection and utilize it.

Comment: You should probably consider batching your data transfers. You can't just dump everything into memory and then dump it to your database in one go.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB documents have a maximum size of 16MB according to the docs

> "The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes.
>
> The maximum document size helps ensure that a single document cannot use excessive amount of RAM or, during transmission, excessive amount of bandwidth. To store documents larger than the maximum size, MongoDB provides the GridFS API..."
> (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/)

It might be worth checking out that GridFS API (but I haven't yet).

Are you trying to insert ONE document that is 16MB+? or are you trying to insert MULTIPLE documents that are adding up to 16MB+?